# Can't link images to permalink page on tumblr

Tags: hyperlink, permalinks

I want to link images on my index page, to their permalink page, but the tags don't seem to be working. It's not that the images are not linking to the correct place, they're simply not being rendered as links at all.

This is the code:

```
{block:Photo}
                <article id="{PostID}" class="post photo">
                    **<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" href="{Permalink}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>**

                    {block:IndexPage}
                     <div style="{block:ifShowPhotoCaption} display: none; {/block:ifShowPhotoCaption}"  class="control">
                <a href="{Permalink}" title="Permalink Page" class="notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>
```

This should link the image on the index page to its permalink page, but it doesn't create a link at all, in the same way 'note count' label does, in the second block of code.

I've tried:

```
<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"><a href="{Permalink}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
```

Instead of the code I posted, but it makes no difference. I've also tried moving the {block:IndexPage} to before the {block:Photo} tag, but this doesn't work, and also has the effect of messing up the permalink page when I view it through the 'notes count' link.

My tumblr: http://ginnypig.tumblr.com/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

The code needed to be:

```
<a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/></a>
```

As opposed to what I was using:

```
<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" href="{Permalink}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
```